# No data is populated in Database files after implementing SQL Cipher in Room Database in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, sqlcipher-android

Cipher Encryption is working fine but Database files contains no data when downloaded from Android Studio and open with DB browser for SQLite after implementing SQL Cipher in Room Database

```
val passphrase: ByteArray = net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.getBytes(
                AppConstants.DB_KEY.toCharArray()
            )
            val factory = SupportFactory(passphrase)
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                NeDatabase::class.java,
                DATABASE_NAME
            )
                .openHelperFactory(factory)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_5_6, MIGRATION_6_7)
                .addCallback(DbApplicationCallback())
                .build()
```

Need To get Database tables and datas after implementing Cipher

Comment: 1) Have you read https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Encrypted-Databases and perhaps importantly ***Providing you have a SQLCipher version of DB Browser for SQLite you simply need to select "Set Encryption" from the "Tools" menu and enter your chosen password.***. 2) are you downloading all the files, noting that by default Room uses **WAL** which applies changes to the -wal file. In short if the -wal file  is not empty then part of the database is in the -wal file. the -wal file is the same name as the database file name suffixed with -wal. Best to also copy -shm file.

Comment: thanks for replying .I'm already using  DB Browser for SQLite(Cipher) . I copied all 3 files (database,database-shm,database-wal) . the browser asks for key and encryption works fine. But there is no datas or tables inside the DB . If i remove openHelpfactory(factory) it works fine